# Embedding BandCamp player in UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

I'm trying to embed a bandcamp music player into my app. Although their players are generally Flash-based, they are HTML5 when loaded in iOS mobile Safari. Trouble is, it only seems to work in mobile Safari itself... when I try to embed a player in a UIWebView, it tells me my browser is unsupported. Is there any way around this or am I hosed?

Example URL (obtained from the "Share" button on any bandcamp player):
http://bandcamp.com/EmbeddedPlayer/album=355390343/size=grande3/bgcol=000000/linkcol=1275c4/

Answer (score 0):

This is, because the user agent the UIWebView sends by default is another one than the one MobileSafari uses. The default is `WebApps/1.0 CFNetwork/339.3 Darwin/9.4.1` and the one used by MobileSafari `Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/1A543 Safari/419.3`

You can change the user agent sent by using the method

```
- (void)setValue:(NSString *)value forHTTPHeaderField:(NSString *)field
```

Take a look at the documentation to find out more.

This should solve your problem.

Comment: A valiant effort but it looks like the bandcamp player is smart (or stupid) enough to block browser spoofing. Looks like I may have to build my own player :/